# Changing OS X Defaults

Tags: macos

I am wanting to read and otherwise manipulate settings in the **com.apple.iTunes** plist, but the info I'm finding about using the **NSUserDefaults** class doesn't seem to be telling me what I want to know.  Is that maybe not the right place to be looking?

Basically what I need to know is, what is the programatic equivalent of the shell commands:

```
defaults read {plist} {key}

defaults write {plist} {key} {options} {value}

defaults delete {plist} {key}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you’re looking for is the Core Foundation neighbor to NSUserDefaults, CFPreferences; the methods in question would be `CFPreferencesCopyAppValue` and `CFPreferencesSetAppValue`. There’s more information in the [Preferences Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html). Keep in mind that sandboxing might prevent your app from affecting other apps’ settings.

Comment: This looks promising... I'm experimenting with it now.